# Actionscript, making an objects dimensions click-able, possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have imported a vector into Flash Professional and are then importing it into an action script class. The vector is an outline version of an X.

I then attach an event listener like this

```
close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click);
```

The Click event is only called then the inner part of the X is clicked, rather than the space between the legs of the X. How can I make it all click-able.

Previously I generated the X as a text field in the class itself, and every part was click-able, hence the issue now I am using a vector.

Comment: Add a layer with transparent (alpha=0) shape that covers all the areas you want to be also clickable.

Comment: @organis, thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Organis Regarding this, is that really the official way to do this? This is always how I've done it but I have always wondered if it was possible to specify a hit area instead of drawing a graphic atop of the object.

Comment: @quantomworks You might want to try **SimpleButton** with the graphics on the frames 1-3 and hit area on the 4-th frame. I mostly use **SimpleButton** with 4-th frame only, no graphics, basic shapes: 100x100 square or radius 50 circle (since no-graphics **SimpleButton** has WxH of 0x0 it is easy to scale them this way).

Comment: Just do this once: `close.graphics.beginFill(0,0); close.graphics.drawRect(0,0,close.width,close.height);`   that will draw a transparent background on your button.  Or, do as Organis suggests and create one on a layer at design time.

Comment: @BasFeelingABoutThis, thanks, I like that solution also.